# Google App Script Rename Spreadsheet & Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm just wondering if there's a way for me to rename the spreadsheet and sheet names upon running the `SpreadsheetApp.create()` script. I'm attempting to retrieve the value of the name in a specific cell. I'm thinking of getting the `L12` value for the spreadsheet name, and the concatenated value of `D16`, `H16`, and `P16` for the sheet name.

```
  const srcSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = srcSs.getSheetByName("TEMPLATE");
  const values = sheet.getRange("C2").getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues().flat().filter(String);
  const dstSs = SpreadsheetApp.create("SMRtempSpreadsheet");

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("About to take some action... Please wait...");

  values.forEach(v => {
    sheet.getRange("C2").setValue(v);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    const tempSheet = sheet.copyTo(srcSs);
    const range = tempSheet.getDataRange();
    range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});

    var cell = tempSheet.getRange("D19");
    cell.setNumberFormat('mm/dd/yyyy');

    tempSheet.getRange("B2:2").clear().clearDataValidations();
    tempSheet.getDrawings().forEach(e => e.remove());
    tempSheet.deleteColumn(1);
    tempSheet.deleteRow(1);
    tempSheet.deleteRow(2);
    tempSheet.deleteRow(3);
    tempSheet.copyTo(dstSs);
    srcSs.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
  });
  dstSs.deleteSheet(dstSs.getSheets()[0]);
```

[image]

[SAMPLE SPREADSHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vHHLrLdQBRgTliO_ZFmTUSTdkkWla8Lf982lG0MwJ0M/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think that the Spreadsheet name and the sheet name can be renamed. But I cannot understand `I'm thinking of getting the L12 value for the spreadsheet name, and the concatenated value of D16, H16, and P16 for the sheet name.`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike I want to get the value of those cells for the name value of SpreadSheet and Sheet. Is that possible?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I want to get the value of those cells for the name value of SpreadSheet and Sheet. Is that possible?`. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike I updated the question with an image. I want to get the name of spreadsheet and sheet from those cells.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the sample image. From your sample image, you want to retrieve the values from the merged cells of "D17:G17", "H17:N17", "P17:S17" and "O19:S19". Is my understanding is correct?

Comment: By the way, in the case of retrieving the values from the merged cells, when you provide the sample Spreadsheet, I thought that it will help to understand your current situation.

Comment: @Tanaike I attached a sample spreadsheet above. Please see. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for repliyng. I would like to check it.

Comment: When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, it seems that the situation is different between your provided Spreadsheet and your provided image. I'm confused about your question. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike for the spreadsheet name, I want to replace the `SMRtempSpreadsheet` to the value of Grade & Section.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, it seems that the situation is different between your provided Spreadsheet and your provided image. If you want to use the provided sample Spreadsheet, from your provided image, I thought that the spreadsheet name and sheet name might be from "L16" and "D14:S14", respectively. When my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function PrintMultiple() {
  const srcSs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = srcSs.getSheetByName("TEMPLATE");
  const values = sheet.getRange("C2").getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues().flat().filter(String);
  const spreadsheetName = sheet.getRange("L16").getValue();
  const dstSs = SpreadsheetApp.create(spreadsheetName);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("About to take some action... Please wait...");
  values.forEach(v => {
    sheet.getRange("C2").setValue(v);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    const tempSheet = sheet.copyTo(srcSs);
    const range = tempSheet.getDataRange();
    range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
    var cell = tempSheet.getRange("D17");
    cell.setNumberFormat('mm/dd/yyyy');
    tempSheet.getRange("B2:2").clear().clearDataValidations();
    tempSheet.getDrawings().forEach(e => e.remove());
    tempSheet.deleteColumn(1);
    tempSheet.deleteRow(1);
    tempSheet.deleteRow(2);
    tempSheet.deleteRow(3);
    const sheetName = tempSheet.getRange("C11:R11").getValues()[0].filter(String).join(",");
    tempSheet.copyTo(dstSs).setName(sheetName);
    srcSs.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
  });
  dstSs.deleteSheet(dstSs.getSheets()[0]);
}
```

- By this modification, the created Spreadsheet has `spreadsheetName` name and each tab has `sheetName` name.

#### Note:

- I used the delimiter of `,` for the sheet name. When you want to change this, please modify `join(",")`.
- If your actual Spreadsheet is different from your sample Spreadsheet, this modification might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Sorry for the unmatched sample and image. I didn't noticed it. The spreadsheet name works. However, for the sheet name, I need to rename each sheet based on the value of the student name. As you can see when you click the export button, the value changes. I want those value to be the sheet name.

Comment: @cjwrk Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I thought that I could understand your actual goal. So, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize, again.